# How to remove $.hover event added by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

I tried `$.unbind('hover')`, which is not working.

Comment: Are you specifying what element to unbind the event from? eg $("a").unbind("hover")

Comment: Yes,it's added by $("#id").hover(...),and $("#id").unbind('hover') is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I unbind "hover" in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805133/how-do-i-unbind-hover-in-jquery)

Answer (score 76):

The [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) function it's just a [short-hand](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/tags/1.3.2/src/event.js#526) to bind two handlers to the [mouseenter](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseleave) events, you should unbind them:

```
$('#item').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: You can combine those calls: `.unbind('mouseover mouseout');`

Comment: Is it because the listener is added by $.hover(),not by $.bind()?

Comment: i have added the listener by .hover() and it removed fine by .unbind()

Comment: ^ same here. The solution works fine. Should be marked as correct. @CMS, thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 11):

[Api documentation on **hover**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

Example: To unbind the above example use:

```
$("td").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: What is the difference in `off` and `unbind`?

Comment: As defined in [**unbind()**](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/):
_Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind(). (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.)_

Answer (score 2):

tringger unbinding with a click

```
$('.item').click(function() { 
 $('.item').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You could also try:

`$('#item').bind('hover', function(){return false})`

Comment: Binding extra event handlers to an object does not override previously bound handlers. This may well work, since the `return false` may stop the propagation, but it's not a great solution.