# Disable hover effect on icons when they are at bottom of page, else enable hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some icons that are always going to be fixed at the bottom (bottom of the screen, not the end of the page). I want all these icons to be translucent when thy are not at the bottom. They become  opaque when they are at the bottom, and then translucent again when the user scrolls up.

Also, when the icons are translucent and the user hovers over an icon, only that particular icon should become opaque. And there should not be any hover effect when the icons are at the bottom (since the icons are always opaque then).

I made [an attempt here](http://jsfiddle.net/misaal9/5mGzt/4/) but I am unable to disable the hover when icons are at the bottom.

A little off-topic here but is there a way to only detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page. I have commented out an alert in the code. What happens is that the alert is called every time I scroll. I just want the alert to be called once.

Haha. I'm sorry if the question is too twisted. I can rephrase it again if needed. :)

Heres my code below -

HTML -

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="iconTray">
        <img src="icon1.png">
        <img src="icon2.png">
        <img src="icon3.png">
        <img src="icon4.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#main {
    border: solid 1px green;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
#iconTray {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
#iconTray img {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

jQuery -

```
$('#iconTray img').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.4');
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        //bottom of page
        $('#iconTray img').css('opacity', 1);
        // i basically want to disable hover here when the user is 
        //at the bottom of the page, but i really dont know how to :P 
    } else {
        // this alert is called everytime the user scrolls 
        //alert('yo');
        $('#iconTray img').css('opacity', 0.4);
    }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558365/how-to-remove-hover-event-added-by-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store something in `data()` that you can check on hover :

```
$('#iconTray img').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).data('bottom'))
        $(this).css('opacity', e.type=='mouseenter'? 1 : 0.4);
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var isBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height();

    $('#iconTray img').css('opacity', isBottom ? 1 : 0.4).data('bottom', isBottom)
});
```

The "scrolled to bottom" check seems a little too accurate, but if it's work ...

Comment: This worked just fine. Thanks. I've never really used the .data() before. I learnt something new today.