# Start hover on mousedown and stop on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a `<section>` with some `<div>` inside, and I need to multiselect them.

With my script below, I can click to start the selection, but if I release the mouse the hover effect stays.

How can I start `hover` on `mousedown` and stop it on `mouseup`?

My code is here :

```js
var inside = $(".grid");
var button = $(".grid>div");

inside.mousedown(function() {
    button.hover(function() {
      var attribut = $(this).attr("class");
      if (attribut == null) {
        $(this).addClass('check');
        $(this).css({
          "background": "green"
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    inside.off("mousedown");
  });
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
.grid>div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Voulez vous continuez ?</h1>
  <section class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a flag variable `mouse_down` in my example with `mousemove` so you could check the state of mouse when user move it if it's clicked so colorize the divs else do nothing, check the example below.

```js
var inside = $(".grid"); 
var button = $(".grid>div");

var mouse_down=false;

inside.mousedown(function(e){
    mouse_down=true;
})
.mouseup(function(){
    mouse_down=false;
})
.mousemove(function(e){
    if(mouse_down){
        var target = $(e.target);
      
        if (target.is("div")) {
            target.addClass('check');
            target.css({
                "background":"green"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid{
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.grid>div{
  display: flex;
  margin:5px;
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1>Voulez vous continuez ?</h1>
  <section class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>   
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>   
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558365/how-to-remove-hover-event-added-by-jquery) and [the API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), to remove the `hover` event you should use:

```
$('#myItem').off('mouseenter mouseleave')
```

```js
var inside = $(".grid");
var button = $(".grid>div");

inside.mousedown(function() {
  button.hover(function() {
    var attribut = $(this).attr("class");
    if (attribut == null) {
      $(this).addClass('check');
      $(this).css({
        "background": "green"
      });
    }
  });
});

inside.mouseup(function() {
  button.off("mouseenter mouseleave");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
.grid>div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Voulez vous continuez ?</h1>
  <section class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</body>
```