# How to remove mouse-over/-out events on specific jQuery mobile buttons?

Tags: javascript, button, jquery-mobile, mouseevent, jquery-events

I need to remove the functionality that adds/removes the button class 'ui-btn-up-' or 'ui-btn-hover-' to jQuery mobile generated buttons. How could I do that?

Comment: Havent use jQuery mobile, so dont know how it binds events, but maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805133/how-do-i-unbind-hover-in-jquery

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: currently using 1.3.1

Comment: unfortunately .unbind('mouseenter mouseleave') doesn't work.

Comment: `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/skFZC/

Comment: you mean I would have to add my own listeners and stop event propagation there? hm, that would work but then I also could just overwrite the CSS behaviour...