# New class keeps old class behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I'm taking by first babysteps in jQuery and stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to get around.

I couldn't find an article that quite described what my problem was, so I would like to try to get an answer this way.

I don't understand why my objects keep behaving like their former class.
When I setup a hover action for a class, and change the class of the object by clicking, jQuery keeps doing the animation for the new class.

I used `toggleClass()` and `removeClass`/ `addClass`without any result:

https://jsfiddle.net/biest9160/f0na6sro/

```js
var wide = function() {
  $(this).animate({ 'width': '120px' }, 200);
}

var normal = function() {
  $(this).animate({ 'width': '100px' }, 200);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.class1').hover(wide, normal);

  $('.class1').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
}
.class2 {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box1</div>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box2</div>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box3</div>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box4</div>
```

I don't understand why the the hover action is triggered while the object has a new class.

Comment: This isn't an answer or really related to your problem. But you will want to avoid using id's with the same name, for example `id="box1" `. These should all be unique, just FYI.

Comment: With the content of the div incrimenting the box number, I'm assuming the OP just forgot to change the ID number ^^.

Comment: I was a bit to fast copy/pasting this code to JSFiddle. Thanks anyway! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialy  you attach the *event* to the `element` with the `class` name. After the `class` is changed the *event* remains on the `element`.

To remove the *event* you can use [`.unbind`](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/). To remove `.hover` *event* you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805243/3790486).

A working example using `.unbind` to remove the *event* and after to reattach it will look like in the snippet (basically is *toggle hover event*):

```js
var wide = function(){
    $(this).animate({'width':'120px'},200);
}

var normal = function(){
    $(this).animate({'width' : '100px'},200);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class1').hover(wide,normal);
    
    $('.class1').click(function(event){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); // remove hover
        if( $this.hasClass('class2'))
        {
            $this.hover(wide, normal); // reattach hover
        }
        $this.toggleClass('class1 class2');
    })
})
```

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
}

.class2{
    background: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box1</div>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box2</div>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box3</div>
<div id="box1" class="class1">box4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.on()` menthod to bind the event which will actually bind the event on the parent of the class.

Here is the example:

```
$(document).on("click", '.class1', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
    });
```

This will defiantly work...