# JQuery on("click") effect happens but doesn't last after moving mouse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I'm having the following problem.
On the snippet below you'll see parts of a larger page project I'm creating.
I've a parent DIV that has 2 main children in the form of flex:row - left and right side.
(With lots of sub-divs/classes each, that are not displayed here)

The "Products" button is an element/class that belongs in the "Left Side".
The Image (color in this snippet) is an element/class that belongs in the "Right Side".
When you click on the "Products" button, 2 other buttons appear, and then, when you hover to any of the 3 buttons, the image of the "Right Side" (color) changes accordingly.
What I want is to click on the "All Products" button, and change the image(color) of the "Right Side".
But what happens, is that it changes after I click, but the moment I move my mouse, it changes back.
This doesn't happen when I hover in any of the 3 buttons.
The image changes but it remains the same, wherever I move my mouse, as it should, unless I hover to another button.

I tried some methods but I didn't come up with any solution.
Any ideas, ladies and gentlemen?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var btn_state = true


    $("#main_pr_btn").on("click", function(){
        if (btn_state != false){
            btn_state = false;
            $("#main_pr_btn").addClass("active");
            $("#all_pr_btn").fadeIn(0300);
            $("#recipes").fadeIn(0600); 
        }
        else
        {
            btn_state = true;
            $("#main_pr_btn").removeClass("active");
            $("#all_pr_btn").fadeOut(0200);
            $("#recipes").fadeOut(0400);
        }
    })

    $("#main_pr_btn").hover(function(){
        $(".right_side_img").css({"box-shadow": "45px 45px 150px 50px rgb(255, 255, 255)"});
        $(".right_side_img").css({"background-color": "white", "background-size": "115%"});
    })

    $("#all_pr_btn").hover(function(){
        $(".right_side_img").css({"box-shadow": "-45px 35px 100px 20px rgb(255, 255, 255)"});
        $(".right_side_img").css({"background-color": "red", "background-size": "180%"});          
    })
    
    $("#recipes").hover(function(){
        $(".right_side_img").css({"box-shadow": "0px 0px 150px 50px #80ffcc"});
        $(".right_side_img").css({"background-color": "blue", "background-size": "140%"});
    })

    $("#all_pr_btn").on("click", function(){
        $(".right_side_img").css({"background-color": "yellow", "background-size": "140%"});
        
        $(".left_side_first_page").find("#buttons").css({
            "visibility": "hidden",
            "opacity" : "0",
            "transition" : "0.3s ease-in-out"
        });
    })
})
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(35deg, #073b0e, rgb(2, 17, 54));
  font-family: "Aloevera", sans-serif;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.section_1 {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 5%;
  font-family: "Didact Gothic";
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side {
  flex: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-break: break-all;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 70vh;
  padding: 1vh;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-break: break-all;
  height: 70vh;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 20%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons .active button {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #main_pr_btn button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #d6ee00, rgb(0, 247, 255));
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #main_pr_btn button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 24.5px;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #all_pr_btn {
  display: none;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #all_pr_btn button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #d6ee00, rgb(0, 247, 255));
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #all_pr_btn button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 24.5px;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #recipes {
  display: none;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #recipes button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #d6ee00, rgb(0, 247, 255));
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_first_page #buttons #recipes button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 24.5px;
}
.section_1 .parent_left_side .left_side_second_page {
  background-color: rgb(0, 71, 62);
  display: none;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 10px #ffffff, 0px 0px 20px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.section_1 .right_side {
  flex: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-break: break-all;
  height: 60vh;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1vh;
}
.section_1 .right_side .right_side_img {
  background-color: white;
  height: 55vh;
  width: 55vh;
  background-size: 115%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 45px 45px 150px 50px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mycss/style.css">
        <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/aloevera" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya Sans SC' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact Gothic' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="section_1">
            <div class="parent_left_side">
                <div class="left_side_first_page">
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <div id="main_pr_btn">
                            <button type="button">
                                Products
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="all_pr_btn">
                            <button type="button">
                                All Products
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="recipes">
                            <button type="button">
                                Recipes
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left_side_second_page">                    
                </div>
            <div class="right_side">
                <div class="right_side_img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="../myjs/mainpage.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#all_pr_btn, #main_pr_btn , #recipes").off('mouseenter mouseleave');` add this line inside `$("#all_pr_btn").on("click", function(){` .. You can take a look at [How do I unbind "hover" in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805133/how-do-i-unbind-hover-in-jquery)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you very much, I just did and it straight out worked! <3

Comment: Glad it helped ..You'r totally welcome .. Have a great day :)